# Multiple Many-to-many relationships in Ember-Data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

How to make Ember-Data to recognize **multiple** many-to-many relationships between the models?

User

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  groups: DS.hasMany('group')
});
```

Group

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  members: DS.hasMany('user'),
  inactive_members: DS.hasMany('user')
});
```

The error

> You defined the 'groups' relationship on frontend@model:user:, but multiple possible inverse relationships of type frontend@model:user: were found on frontend@group:.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You need to explicitly set the inverse on the User model as follows](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/models/defining-models/#toc_explicit-inverses):

`groups: DS.hasMany('group', { inverse: 'members' })`

Comment: I tried that. You get exception inside the Ember Data - "Adapter operation failed"

Comment: What adapter operation failed? What exactly are you trying to do when you get this error?

Comment: The default adapter. I'm not doing anything. It's happening on the Ember Data initialisation. I can crop my app to a reproducible sample if you are willing to debug.

Comment: Could you try get an example on JSBin?

Comment: Yep. Tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: The "Adapter operation failed" is how Ember Data tells you about network errors. Brilliant! :)
The good news is - your answer is absolutely correct. It did fix the issue. Thank you.